# Repeated measure friedman.test

Tags: r, statistics

I want to use the  Friedman.test to make a repeated measured. 
I want compare the difference between the (`pre1` and `after1`) with (`pre2` `after2`). 1 and 2 are two different drugs. Pre1 (before taking drug 1) after1 (after took drug 2).

Example:

```
df <- data.frame(Name= rep(c("a","b","c","d"), times=4), Blocks = c(rep("pre1",time=4), rep("after1",time=4), rep("pre2",time=4), rep("after2",time=4)), group= rep(c("1","1","1","1","2","2","2","2"), time=2), Value=runif(16, 5.0, 7.5))

friedman.test(Value ~ Blocks | Name, data=df)
```

To this I should add the idea that each pre1 and after 1 are together.
so:

```
friedman.test(Value ~ Blocks | Name, data=df, groups = group)

ERROR: Error in model.frame.default(formula = Value ~ Blocks + Name, data = df,  : 
  invalid type (pairlist) for variable '(...)'
```

Why this error? How to reach my goal?

Comment: Check formula, the help file mentions: 
a formula of the form a ~ b | c, where a, b and c give the data values and corresponding groups and blocks, respectively

Comment: So, it is not possible to do what I decribed in up with this formula...
To apply only this:

friedman.test(Value ~ Blocks | Name, data=df)

I think it is not correct because the information about "pre" and "after" treatment is missed.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for late reply,

Based on [this post](http://www.r-bloggers.com/beware-the-friedman-test/), and recommending the use of `data.table`:

```
    library ( data.table, nlme )
    Longitudinal <- data.table ( cbind (
     expand.grid ( Subject = letters [ 1:4 ], Time = 1:2, Drug = 1:2 ),
     Value = runif ( 16, 5.0, 7.5 )))

    Longitudinal [, ValueRank := rank ( Value )]

    Fit <- lme ( fixed = ValueRank ~ Time + Drug,
      random = ~1|Subject, data = Longitudinal )
    anova ( Fit )
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! Can I ask you an elucidation about "random = ~1|Subject" This script on my data doesn't work.. with error:
Error in MEEM(object, conLin, control$niterEM) : 
  Singularity in backsolve at level 0, block 1